# Set border for sections in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to create the collection view like this:
[image]

the problem is I want to make a round corner border for each section and change its background color too. Can anyone show me how?

Comment: Take a UITableView and at each index of your tableview you can have a collectionview. And you can give corner radius to each tableview cell

Comment: yeah everything would be easier if i can use a UITableView :( , the problem is i must use a UICollectionView :(

Comment: Then use two collectionviews

Comment: With some effort you can achieve what you're looking for by creating a custom [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout)

Comment: Hey your solution is great @Coder, thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve such `UICollectionView` appearance with some custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. Supplementary views can help with background!

I can advice [SquareMosaicLayout](https://github.com/iwheelbuy/SquareMosaicLayout) that can be customised to look like on the image you provided. Screenshot shows that is very simple to achieve the desired appearance. It just lacks borders between cells, but you can do it yourself easily.

P.S. I've added your layout to the repository, so you can download and run the project.

[image: SquareMosaicLayout]

Full code using SquareMosaicLayout:

```
import UIKit
import SquareMosaicLayout

final class Hungcao: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let collection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: HungcaoLayout())
        collection.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collection.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 60.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 20.0)
        collection.register(UICollectionViewCell.self)
        collection.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, identifier: SquareMosaicLayoutSectionBacker, kind: SquareMosaicLayoutSectionBacker)
        collection.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, identifier: SquareMosaicLayoutSectionHeader, kind: SquareMosaicLayoutSectionHeader)
        collection.dataSource = self
        self.title = "Hungcao"
        self.view = collection
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueCell(indexPath: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row)"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
        cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case SquareMosaicLayoutSectionBacker:
            let view: UICollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueSupplementary(kind, indexPath: indexPath, kind: kind)
            view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground.cgColor
            view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
            view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            return view
        case SquareMosaicLayoutSectionHeader:
            let view: UICollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueSupplementary(kind, indexPath: indexPath, kind: kind)
            view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "header"
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.frame = view.bounds
            view.addSubview(label)

            return view
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}

final class HungcaoLayout: SquareMosaicLayout, SquareMosaicDataSource {

    convenience init() {
        self.init(direction: SquareMosaicDirection.vertical)
        self.dataSource = self
    }

    func layoutPattern(for section: Int) -> SquareMosaicPattern {
        return HungcaoPattern()
    }

    func layoutSupplementaryBackerRequired(for section: Int) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func layoutSeparatorBetweenSections() -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0
    }

    func layoutSupplementaryHeader(for section: Int) -> SquareMosaicSupplementary? {
        return HungcaoSupplementary()
    }
}

final class HungcaoSupplementary: SquareMosaicSupplementary {

    func supplementaryFrame(for origin: CGFloat, side: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: origin, width: side, height: 60)
    }
}

final class HungcaoPattern: SquareMosaicPattern {

    func patternBlocks() -> [SquareMosaicBlock] {
        return [HungcaoBlock()]
    }
}

public class HungcaoBlock: SquareMosaicBlock {

    public func blockFrames() -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    public func blockFrames(origin: CGFloat, side: CGFloat) -> [CGRect] {
        let width = side / 2.0
        var frames = [CGRect]()
        frames.append(CGRect(x: 0, y: origin, width: width, height: 80))
        frames.append(CGRect(x: width, y: origin, width: width, height: 80))
        frames.append(CGRect(x: 0, y: origin + 80, width: width, height: 80))
        frames.append(CGRect(x: width, y: origin + 80, width: width, height: 80))
        return frames
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewCell

extension UICollectionView {

    func dequeueCell<T:UICollectionViewCell>(_ identifier: String? = nil, indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        let identifier = identifier ?? String(describing: T.self)
        let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as? T
        switch cell {
        case .some(let unwrapped):  return unwrapped
        default:                    fatalError("Unable to dequeue" + T.self.description())
        }
    }

    func register<T:UICollectionViewCell>(_ type: T.Type, identifier: String? = nil) {
        let identifier = identifier ?? String(describing: T.self)
        register(type, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionReusableView

extension UICollectionView {

    func dequeueSupplementary<T:UICollectionReusableView>(_ identifier: String? = nil, indexPath: IndexPath, kind: String) -> T {
        let identifier = identifier ?? String(describing: T.self)
        let view = self.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as? T
        switch view {
        case .some(let unwrapped):  return unwrapped
        default:                    fatalError("Unable to dequeue" + T.self.description())
        }
    }

    func register<T:UICollectionReusableView>(_ type: T.Type, identifier: String? = nil, kind: String) {
        let identifier = identifier ?? String(describing: T.self)
        register(type, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what i need ! Thanks bro !